# Exclude some of the lazy modules from the build (Angular5)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a project, which runs at multiple customers. There are many lazy loaded modules, and most of them is used by all of the customers. But there are some modules, which are only needed in a few places, so I would like to exclude them from the build everywhere else.

Is it possible?

Comment: Can [canload](https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad#canload) help? Or we should remove(do not build) `js` files?

Comment: What's the actual purpose? Since the modules are lazily loaded, they won't load if unused, so there is no performance issue, it will just take a bit more space on HDD but it's derisory

Comment: are you trying to do this by route?  or how does the app know if the module is needed or not?

Comment: @GuerricP seems much more like a compile time issue to me - which would be a greater burden during development

Comment: @Iter Ator Did you find the solution to your problem, I have to implement something like this

Comment: @poojagupta No, there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this: 
(you could then use if statements, etc, to load different modules)

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('testOutlet', {read: ViewContainerRef}) testOutlet: ViewContainerRef;
  constructor(
    private loader: NgModuleFactoryLoader,
    private injector: Injector) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const path = 'src/app/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule';
    this.loader.load(path).then((moduleFactory: NgModuleFactory<any>) => {
      const entryComponent = (<any>moduleFactory.moduleType).entry;
      const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);

      const compFactory = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(entryComponent);
      this.testOutlet.createComponent(compFactory);
  });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the modules to the `exclude` setting in your `tsconfig.app.json` file

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
    "path/to/your/lazy.module.ts"
  ]
}
```

The path must be relative to the `baseUrl` setting

Now I'm not sure how your setup is (multi app cli project? 1 build per customer?) but this should work as long as each build has the correct config file

Comment: I have exclude one module from build but I got an error like this sis.module.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make
sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

Comment: @malbarmawi And you do not reference explicitly that module anywhere in your code, right ? (using `import`)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the current tooling. The AOT compiler has currently (up to V7) no support for conditional loading of routes. As a result, this is also not supported by the CLI. 
You can create a situation that the routes are shielded away from the user by router-guards, but for building, they need to be present. This is because the NGC needs to analyze the router tree statically.
There are some long-term plans that might change this in the future.

If you want to save on your build time, you can move those parts into libraries, but then you still need a small module to be able to lazy load them. (you can't lazy load libraries, for the same reasons.)
There are a couple of issues around this on GitHub around this. [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2601) is a good one to start if you want to dig into this deeper,